# Issues with Python script as service on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Setup details:
RPI Version: Raspberry Pi 2 Model BV1.1
Python Version: 2.7

I have created a small program to control the fan and lights in my hydroponic room. I am using 8 channel relay board with external power supply. Everything works fine if I run script using below command
‘sudo python /home/pi/lionsfort/hydroponic.py’. To stop the execution I type CTRL+C then script stops properly with relay getting power off.

Since I wanted script to start with Raspberry pi, I am running ‘hydroponic.py’ script as a service. But with script running as service created below problems
1.  Only console logs getting written and file logs are empty.
2.  Script starts ok with relay functioning properly, but when I stop the service (sudo systemctl stop hydroponic.service) relay wont get power off.
3.  Script start with raspberry pi power on but also start with every new PUTTY session. There should be only one instance of script running irrespective PUTTY session.

Note: If run script using ‘sudo python /home/pi/lionsfort/hydroponic.py’ I don’t face any of above problems!!

Followed below process to run script as a service on boot: (ref http://www.diegoacuna.me/how-to-run-a-script-as-a-service-in-raspberry-pi-raspbian-jessie/)

```
1.  cd /lib/systemd/system/
2.  sudo nano hydroponic.service
3.  hydroponic.service content

    [Unit]
    Description=Hydroponic
    After=multi-user.target

    [Service]
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/lionsfort/hydroponic.py
    Restart=on-abort

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target

4.  To activate it, I ran below commands
a.  sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/ hydroponic.service
b.  chmod +x /home/pi/lionsfort/hydroponic.py
c.  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
d.  sudo systemctl enable hydroponic.service
e.  sudo systemctl start hydroponic.service
```

### [logging.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kJh1LSFjV5nM_uPH3qph67o7OpGF0KC-/view?usp=sharing)

Satish Gunjal

Comment: Your logging configuration just has a relative filename for the log file. You should probably specify a working directory for the service and a user to run the service under.

Comment: @Duncan Logs issue resolved after giving the full path of the log file. Thanks!  Also please help me on issue 2: command " sudo systemctl stop hydroponic.service" stops service but relays are still power on!

Comment: For that you should add signal handlers for SIGINT and SIGTERM to your script so that you can turn the relays off when the script is terminated. Create a fresh question though if you need more detail.

Comment: i already did that. and everything working fine. thanks